# Find element in res.StatusDescription Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

In this part I can show permission from role. Like this

```
 let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.Login), body, {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        let permissions: any[] = res.StatusDescription.Permisions;
           console.log(permissions)
        if (res.StatusCode === 0 && res.Token) {
          this.currentUser = {
            username: username,
            token: res.Token
          }
          localStorage.setItem(AuthService.CURRENT_USER, JSON.stringify(this.currentUser));
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      );
```

In console show this array. Photo
[image]

Now I want to create function that find element on this array! Can you suggest me, how to implement ?

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like you would want to use `find`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**auths.component.ts**

```
export class AuthsComponent {

permissions:string[] = [];

findPermission(permission:string){
    return this.permissions.find(p => p===permission)
}

// this is your function with some modification
call(){
let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.Login), body, {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        // HERE : set the permissions value
        this.permissions = res.StatusDescription.Permisions;
           console.log(permissions)
        if (res.StatusCode === 0 && res.Token) {
          this.currentUser = {
            username: username,
            token: res.Token
          }
          localStorage.setItem(AuthService.CURRENT_USER, JSON.stringify(this.currentUser));
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      );
    }

    }
```

**auths.component.html**

```
<span *ngIf="findPermission('app_usersgetall')"></span>
```

Comment: return this.permissions.find(p => p === permission) ---> Property 'permissions' does not exist on type

Comment: My bad, I forgot to remote the `this`

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your code? How do you call that function?

Comment: I want to call from html. Like this: *ngIf="auths.findPermission('app_usersgetall')"

Comment: `findPermissions` takes 2 arguments, the permission you wnat to find and the list of permissions so your HTML should look like `*ngIf="auths.findPermission('app_usersgetall', permissions)"` where permissions is a property of your component . I'll post a full answer in a sec

Comment: Thank you, this is good. But,when I refresh site ->Console cannot read property 'find' of undefined. Any idea?

Comment: This means that the `permissions` object in not defined, you can initiatilize it with an empty array : `permissions : any[] = []`